# React Native 0.60.4 detox postinstall.js install error

Tags: react-native, detox

Not able to install detox by `npm install` or `yarn`.

`yarn add --dev detox` will fail out in the postbuild.js`

This question is in response to wix/detox's policy regarding issue tracking:
https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1523

Followed the latest tutorial to get started with detox.

```
react-native init example // (0.60.4)
brew update
brew tap wix/brew
brew install applesimutils
yarn global add detox-cli // you shouldn't need this
yarn add --dev detox // add this package in /example app
```

Installing detox will exit out with a childprocess error.

Error:

```
Command Failed: <YOUR_PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/detox/scripts/build_framework.ios.sh
   at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<YOUR_PROJECT_PATH>/node_modules/detox/scripts/postinstall.js:2:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Followed their guide here:
https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.GettingStarted.md

UPDATE: See the solution below, was able to get detox installed without an issue.

Answer (score 7):

*The detox version that was previously installed required the Legacy Build System*

### How to upgrade correctly:

> 1. Remove ~/Library/Detox/
> 2. Remove ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
> 3. `yarn add -D detox` // installs without and issue

### How did this issue occur:

If you have a previous version of Detox installed which relied on an earlier Xcode you will get a conflict between *Legacy & New Build System*.

Detox will then look at your `~/Library/Detox` data and fail to build due to New Build System being selected as default

I resolved this install error by doing the following:

> 1. In xcode 10.3 go into `File > Workspace Settings`
> 2. Under **Shared Workspace Settings** select **Legacy Build System**
> 3. Re-install detox (it will not use the legacy build and not error out)